# glutWarpPointer for FP camera issue

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am working on a project for mouse control to look around. I have been successful with rotating the camera using the mouse however I am trying to get the mouse to do 360 turns without the mouse leaving the screen before it can fully rotate. I read around and came across `glutWarpPointer()`, where most posts said to use it after getting the difference between the centre and the new mouse position in the window.

The issue this causes with my program is that when I move the mouse it will  rotate very slightly for that frame the restart the location to the original point. Basically it i have a blue ball in front of me and green behind when i try to rotate towards the green ball the camera will move slightly but stay locked on the blue ball.

Is there a way to around or a fix?

```
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);    
    glLoadIdentity();
    //rotate and translating the camera
    glRotatef(-camVert, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glRotatef(-camHor, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(-posx,-posy,-posz);

  //blue and green ball
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glTranslatef(1, 0, 25);
    glutSolidSphere(5, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
    glTranslatef(0, 0, -25);
    glutSolidSphere(5, 20, 20);
    glPopMatrix();
};

void setAngle(float angy, float angx)
{
    camVert = angy*1.5;

    if (camVert > 90)
        camVert = 90;
    else if (camVert < -90)
        camVert = -90;

    camHor = angx*0.5;


}

void MoveCam(float distance, float direction)
{
    float rads = (camHor+direction)*PI / 180;
    posx -= sin(rads)*distance;
    posz -= cos(rads)*distance;
};

void mouseMove(int x, int y)
{

    float diffx = midx - x;
    float diffy = midy - y;

    setAngle(diffy,diffx);
    //glutWarpPointer(glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2, glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2);


}
```

Comment: Use an API for getting callbacks on mouse movement that yields the movement instead of the position. From what I can see glut can´t do that.

Comment: One option for you is to temporarily disable the callbacks when calling glutWarpPointer: glutMouseFunc, glutMotionFunc, glutPassiveMotionFunc, glutEntryFunc.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, what i have tried is to use a timer delay after glutwarppointer() before it can be called again, however this just allows me to move the mouse a certain amount before it puts the camera back in the starting position.